# Input:focus doesn't work on wordpress theme's subscribe form

Tags: php, css, wordpress, subscribe

I'm trying to build a subscribe form on wordpress theme. The inputs only have border-bottom, which I have styled in css. However, when I try to repeat the same operation for input:focus, the border remains unchanged. How do I resolve this problem?

```
footer input:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0.1vmin solid honeydew;
}
```

Comment: Have a look in your devtools (F12) and see if those styles are actually being applied. There may be other rules overriding it, or your might have misspelled a selector.

Comment: when I use dev too, I indeed do not see any :focus selector. Hmm. How do solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When everything else fails you can always play it dirty with

```
!important
```

```css
footer input{
border-bottom:2px solid red!important;
}
footer input{
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
footer input.test{
border-bottom:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<input class="test" type="text">
</footer>
```

Tags marked by important overrule pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you are checking in the devtools, make sure you actually have the input focused, otherwise the `:focus` style rules won't show in the devtools list. Then scroll down the list and check if your css rule is anywhere in the list (it may be lower down if it is overriden). If it isn't, check that you are using the correct css selector. If the selector is definitely correct, you probably aren't loading the styles correctly.